# How to check if an object has certain properties with flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a javascript function:

```
function foo(obj: Object): any { return 42; }
```

I want to make sure the input
object has a property named 'name' on it, how can I do that with flow?

Answer (score 5):

Using `{name: string}` will assert that any object that comes in to the function must have a `name` property whose value is a string:

```
function foo(obj: {name: string}): any { return 42; }
```

Because Flow represents object types structurally, you can pass any object that has *at least* a `name` property to this annotation.